# In highchart in R how to create this line + bar chart

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts

I need to replicate this chart using highchart R package:

https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/stocktools/navigation-annotation-options

I think the answer is in here: series:

```
[{
            type: 'line',
            id: 'aapl-ohlc',
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: ohlc
        }, {
            type: 'column',
            id: 'aapl-volume',
            name: 'AAPL Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
```

It looks like I need to use `hc_add_series` function with 2 series inside, right?

But its not easy for me.

```
library(highcharter)
library(gapminder)
 
gapminder %>%  filter(country == c("Chile","Argentina")) %>%
    hchart("line",
           hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can combine the line and column series. However, to use the range selector, I think that that is limited to chart type "stock". I've put together several examples. The first of which shows you how you can add the range selector. The others show how you can add disparate series.

I modified the data to add a date field. This field is only used in the first example for the range selector. You could just use the field 'year', but it changes the labels on the x-axis to nonsense. That could be changed, as well. I just went with what I thought was a bit easier.

For this graph, note that I have two series calls and two y-axis calls. In the y-axis calls, you'll find `relative`. `relative` indicates the size relative to the other sizes you provide. I believe the rest should be somewhat self-explanatory if you have any understanding of `highcharter`.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

data(gapminder)

gp <- gapminder %>% filter(country %in% c("Chile", "Argentina")) %>% 
  mutate(dt = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01"), 
                      format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = "GMT"))

highchart(type = "stock") %>% hc_rangeSelector(verticalAlign = "bottom") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(type = "datetime") %>% 
  hc_add_series(gp, "line", hcaes(x = dt, y = pop, group = country), yAxis = 0) %>% 
  hc_add_yAxis(title = list(text = "Population"), relative = 2) %>%
  hc_add_series(gp, "column", 
                hcaes(x = dt, y = gdpPercap), yAxis = 1, showInLegend = F) %>% 
  hc_add_yAxis(title = list(text = "GDP per capita"), relative = 1L)
```

[image]

Here are a few other options for arranging the axes.

```
hchart(gp, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country), yAxis = 0) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Population"), relative = 3) %>% 
  hc_add_series(gp, "column", hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap),
                yAxis = 1, showInLegend = F) %>% 
  hc_add_yAxis(title = list(text = "GDP"), relative = 1)
```

[image]

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_yAxis_multiples(create_axis(2,  height = c(4, 1), turnopposite = T)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(gp, "line", hcaes(x = year, y = pop, group = country), yAxis = 0) %>%
  hc_add_series(gp, "column", hcaes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, 
                                    group = country), yAxis = 1)
```

[image]